# Automatic Screenshot

Tags: java, web, screenshot

I take a lot of screenshots of websites (thousands/month).

Each screenshot captured should include address bar of the browser (top), taskbar of the desktop (bottom) and webpage (in between) plus i need each saved image file to be named after the website's url.

Can anyone suggest me any software ? I tried several s/w, none supported this .
Can I do this using java or any other language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can do it using Java. Have a look at the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) Class therefore.
The method [createScreenCapture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) should exactly do what you are looking for.